# Finding A Child Element If It Exists When Manipulating PowerPoint XML With python-pptx

Tags: python, python-pptx

In md2pptx - which uses python-pptx to turn Markdown into PowerPoint - I've implemented a few functions that manipulate the XML tree.

In a few places I need to find a child element if it exists - and create it if it doesn't.

I have a rather hacky way of searching for this element. I'd rather have a decent way.

So, could someone post me the "right" way to search for a child element's existence.

There's probably a more general version of this question - how to manipulate XML in the context of python-pptx. I could use a reference for that, too. (Yes, I can read the python-pptx code and often do - but a synopsis would help me get it right.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using XPath for this job is almost always the right answer.

For example, if you wanted to get all the `a:fld` child elements of a paragraph to implement something to do with text fields:

```
# --- get <a:p> XML element of paragraph ---
p = paragraph._p
# --- use XPath to get all the `<a:fld>` child elements ---
flds = p.xpath("./a:fld")
# --- do something with them ---
for fld in flds:
    do_fieldy_thing(fld)
```

The result of an `.xpath()` call is a list of the zero-or-more items that matched the `str` XPath expression provided as its argument. If there can only be zero or one result it's common to process it like this instead:

```
if flds:
    do_fieldy_thing(flds[0])
```

The complication arises when the "starting" element (`p` in this case) is not a defined `oxml` element. `oxml` is a layer of custom element classes added by `python-pptx` "on top of" the base `lxml.etree._Element` class for each XML element. These custom element classes provide some convenience services, in particular allowing you to specify elements using their namespace prefixes (like `"a:fld"` in this case).

Not all elements in `python-pptx` have a custom element class, only those we manipulate via the API in some way. Any element you get from a `python-pptx` object (like `paragraph._p` above) will be oxml elements, but the elements returned by the `.xpath()` calls very likely won't be (otherwise you would have used `python-pptx` to get them). Elements that are *not* oxml elements are plain `lxml.etree._Element` instances.

The `.xpath()` implementation on an `lxml.etree._Element` instance requires use of so-called "Clark names" which look something like: `"{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main}fld"` instead of `"a:fld"`.

You can create a Clark-name from a namespace-prefixed tag name using the `pptx.oxml.ns.qn()` function:

```
>>> from pptx.oxml.ns import qn
>>> qn("a:fld")
'{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main}fld'
```

Comment: Thank you @scanny! It gets me a long way forwards. I can see myself refactoring in a few places in md2pptx.